# Convergence to a Uniform Distribution

Tags: distributions, convergence, uniform-distribution, asymptotics

$\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor} $

Show that if $P(X_n = i/n)=1/n$ for every $i = 1,...,n$, then $X_n$ converges in distribution to a uniformly distributed random variable $X$.

Convergence in distribution is defined as

$$P(X_n \leq x) \rightarrow P(X \leq x)$$

and I have that a uniform distribution with parameters $a$ and $b$ implies that

$$P(X \leq x) = \frac{x-a}{b-a}$$

I cannot go any further however. I feel like I don't know anything about $X_n$ - I don't even know if it is continuous or discrete. What I can just say is that

$$P(X_n \leq x) = \sum_{i=1}^\floor{x} \frac{1}{n}$$

where $\floor{x}$  means rounding $x$ to the closest lower integer.

Comment: (1) $X_n$ clearly is discrete: all its probability is concentrated on $n$ distinct values.  (2) Please check your calculation of the probability: you seem not to have seen the occurrence of "$i$" in the original formula (or perhaps are ignoring its division by $n$). (3) I believe considerable insight can be obtained by *graphing* the CDFs of the first few $X_n$ as well as of the limiting distribution.

Comment: Thanks. I think I have problems interpreting $X_n$. Can you help? For example, if I have $n=10$, and $x = 5.5$, then what will $P(X_n \leq x)$ be?

Comment: You might find it easier first to answer questions of the form "what is $\Pr(X_{10}=1/10),$ what is $\Pr(X_{10}=2/10),$ ..., and what is $\Pr(X_{10}=10/10)$?"  With those answers in hand it should become apparent what $\Pr(X_{10}\lt 0)$ and $\Pr(X_{10}\gt 1)$ are; and you can then begin graphing the CDF.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**I want to make two points.**  One is that although the concepts in this exercise are relatively sophisticated, a completely elementary simple solution is available.  The other is that an appropriate *visualization* of the problem can lead us in natural steps through a *rigorous proof.*  I will demonstrate that, by pointing out visually evident patterns in a set of graphs and then *proving* that those patterns are correct, using nothing more than the most basic properties of numbers and limits.

---

Because convergence in distribution is defined in terms of the (pointwise) convergence of the distribution functions, let's understand the latter.

Define $F_n$ to be the distribution of $X_n.$  That is,

$$F_n(x) = {\Pr}(X_n\le x).$$

Because $X_n$ can take on only a finite set of values--namely, $1/n, 2/n, \ldots, (n-1)/n, n/n=1$--it is necessarily discrete.  This allows us to express its distribution $F_n(x)$ as the *sum* of probabilities of all numbers less than or equal to $x.$

Because all the possible values of all $X_n$ are greater than $0$ and less than or equal to $1,$ we immediately deduce that $F_n(x)=0$ when $x\le 0$ and $F_n(x)=1$ when $x \ge 1.$  What about intermediate values, $x\in(0,1)$?  To find these, we may simply multiply $x$ by $n.$  This converts $i/n$ to $i$, whence

$$F_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}\text{ times the number of integers in }\{1,2,3,\ldots, n\}\text{ less than or equal to } nx.$$

The expression in words describes the *floor* function (aka *greatest integer* function), which associates with any real number $x$ the largest integer less than or equal to $x.$ 
 This is more compactly written

$$F_n(x) = \lfloor xn \rfloor / n.\tag{1}$$

**Let's plot a few of these functions,** shown in the first three red graphs from left to right.  The blue graph maps $x$ to $x$ for $0\lt x\lt 1$ and otherwise is $0$ for negative $x$ and equal to $1$ for $x\ge 1.$  It is shown for reference.  Let $F_\infty$ denote the function of which it is the graph.

[image: Figure]

**Another pattern emerges:** the red curves never rise above the reference blue curve.  That means $F_n(x) \le x$ for all $x.$  This is an immediate consequence of $(1),$ because the floor function is defined as the largest of a set of *smaller* values.

**Visually, the red graphs grow closer to the blue graph as $n$ increases.**  It's tempting to leap to the conclusion that the blue graph must be their limit.  Be careful, though, because they don't do this consistently at every point.  For instance, for $n=3$ the red graph for $F_n$ touches the blue one at $x=1/3$ and $x=2/3,$ but when we increase $n$ to $4,$ its graph will no longer touch the blue one at those points.

**The situation isn't all that complicated, though.**  You can *see* that the red graphs depart no further than $1/n$ from the blue graph at any point.  Algebraically, in terms of the notation $(1),$ this claim is established by noting that the floor of any number $x$ is never more than $1$ away from $x$ itself, whence

$$|F_n(x) - F_\infty(x)| = |x - \lfloor nx \rfloor / n| = |nx - \lfloor nx \rfloor|/n \le \frac{1}{n}.$$

A basic fact of real numbers is that they are *Archimedian*: the sizes of the integers $1,2,3,\ldots, n,\ldots$ increase without bound.  Therefore the sizes of the foregoing differences $1/n$ converge to $0$ as $n$ increases without bound. That is, by definition, what it means for

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} F_n(x) = F_\infty(x).$$

We have just proven that for $0\lt x\lt 1,$ $F_n(x)$ converges (uniformly!) to $F_\infty(x).$  For all other $x$, $F_n(x) = F_\infty(x).$  Consequently the convergence occurs everywhere.

Because $F_\infty$ is the uniform distribution function for the interval $[0,1],$ we are done.

Answer (score 1):

By the way the information is given, namely that it tells us that the probability of $X_n$ taking a specific value is strictly positive, we learn that $X_n$ is certainly a discrete random variable, otherwise we would have $P(X_n = i/n)=0$ (and I guess we can assume that mixed distributions, part discrete part continuous, are not considered here).

Moreover, given $P(X_n = i/n)=1/n$, we learn that for every finite $n$, $X_n$ is a discrete uniform random variable with support $\{1,2,...,n\}$. What the exercise asks you to examine is whether, as $n \to \infty$, $X_n$ becomes at the limit a *continuous* uniform random variable. Does it?

The issue is trickier to examine than it may look at first, because the Uniform distribution, discrete or continuous, is defined in a bounded support (domain). If we let $n\to \infty$ the domain becomes infinite from the one side.

Certainly, for $n$ "very large" but finite, the distribution intuitively will be practically indistinguishable from the truly continuous uniform distribution. But to formalize "practically indistinguishable" without officially using $n\to \infty$, it appears you may need to use careful epsilon-delta limit arguments.

Comment: The point about the variation in the supports of the RVs is good, but it isn't relevant to distribution functions, which *always* have the entire set of real numbers for their domains.  I am concerned that failure to recognize this distinction (between support of a RV and domain of its CDF) may be at the root of some confusion expressed in many other questions here on CV.